# Options for humidifier

Tags: furnace, humidifier

Winter is approaching and the cool weather is making the air dry in our home. We're using room humidifiers but want to install a humidifier which can go on our furnace. However, we have very limited room and I wanted to know if there is a humidifier which can be mounted outside the furnace.

[image]

Comment: Most humidifiers are mounted on the side of the return duct (with an opening into the duct), with a bypass to the supply ducts. This allows cool return air to pick up moisture, and be mixed into the warm dry air leaving the furnace.

Comment: @Tester101 There is not enough room to mount a humidifier on the return duct. When I meant *outside*, I meant away from the physical unit.

Comment: Depends on the humidifier. They come in all different shapes and sizes.  You might even be able to find one that mounts to the wall, and uses ducting to move the air through it.  Or you might be able to create your own ducting to accomplish a similar setup.

Comment: Mounting it on a wall would be a good solution. I'm hoping someone will be able to provide some guidance with that.

Comment: Aprilaire; and likely others, offer [Steam humidifiers](http://www.aprilaire.com/whole-house-products/whole-house-products/humidifiers/model-800).